# Is there some way to indicate start and finish of the string I want to match

Tags: r, regex

I am trying to match exact text.  In the code below I tried using /b**2016**/b to split on spaces following 2016, but this matches 0,1,2, or 6.  In which way do I indicate start and finish of string I want to match in my code below so that `strsplit` only splits following the two 2016's.  Thanks

```
x <- "January 2016 February 2016     411,236    410,236     gold   54  end 6  only"

strsplit(x, "(?<=[/b2016/b])\\s+", perl = TRUE)
[[1]]
[1] "January 2016"     "February 2016"    "411,236"         
[4] "410,236"          "gold   54  end 6" "only"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Omit the brackets:

```
strsplit(x, "(?<=2016)\\s+", perl = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks that was simple enough

Answer (score 1):

We can use `str_extract` to extract only the 4 digit numbers

```
library(stringr)
str_extract_all(x, "\\b[0-9]{4}\\b")[[1]]
```

Or to be more exact

```
str_extract_all(x, "(?<=[A-Za-z]{1,8}\\s)\\b[0-9]{4}\\b")[[1]]
#[1] "2016" "2016"
```

Comment: Thanks again.  You might recognize this it is from your help in my last question.  There is no way to split on a space following the the exact string `2016`?

Answer (score 0):

You can better use a `gsub` function for your goal:

```
gsub("2016", "2 0 1 6",x)
```

which is replacing one character sequence by another. The result is:

```
[1] "January 2 0 1 6 February 2 0 1 6     411,236    410,236     gold   54  end 6  only"
```